# How to make images the same size

Tags: html, css

I have searched through a few of the questions on stack overflow relating to this issue however the solution did not work.

I have created a row of images and I want the images to be the same size.

my code:

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.products-row {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid products-row row">
  <div><img src="https://article.images.consumerreports.org/prod/content/dam/CRO%20Images%202019/Magazine/04April/CR-Cars-InlineHero-ComingSoon-Toyota-Supra-2-19">
  </div>

  <div><img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5aa18e3edc9df6500b90747b/master/pass/CarRoundup-Mclaren.jpg"></div>

  <div><img src="https://www.autocar.co.uk/sites/autocar.co.uk/files/styles/body-image/public/911-road-3629a.jpg?itok=m6x23Go0"></div>

  <div><img src="https://cdn2.carbuyer.co.uk/sites/carbuyer_d7/files/2017/12/lamborghini-urus-8_1.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: setting the height of image did not help? like 400px?

Comment: @Saksham this does not help as it effects the quality of the image

Comment: When your images have different aspect ratios, then you will not be able to display them at the same size (meaning same width AND same height) without adding some degree of distortion to some of your images.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can set the resolution by inputting height and width values. It worked for me.

```
    img {

  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
}
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.products-row {

    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
 }
```

[So then you should end up with something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqxCN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your images have a different ratio, therefore will never have the same height if they have the same width. My recommendation: set the height to a fixed value, and set the width to auto. See the link below.

https://codepen.io/Darthlegos/pen/eazxjy

```
img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, you should switch to setting `background-image` to containers rather than using image tags

This would help you maintain the aspect ration of your images despite of the width available.

Sample at https://jsfiddle.net/saksham_malhotra/46zutfjm/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=46zutfjm

Remember to set the height of each container to the minimum of all the image heights.

Answer (score 0):

"Same size" can be extremely relative depending on what you mean. To show what I mean, I've created a sample app that shows the different usages of the `object-fit` style attribute. In this example:

- Fill has the same width and height for all images
- Contain has the same height (because the divs containing the images are wider than taller)
- Cover has the same width and height but blows up the images so they fill the space and focus on the center

I also added all the other object-fit options so you can see the differences between all of them, not just filling the space.

I hope an interactive demo helps you decide which you want!

Legal Disclaimer: I do not claim ownership of any of the images used here... I just found them via a search engine and used them based on sizes.

```js
/// Changes the object-fit style when a radio button is clicked
function onChange(e) {
  let imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
  for (let img of imgs) {
    img.style.objectFit = e.target.value;
  }
}

/// Generate the render buttons because I'm lazy
function renderRadioButtons() {
  let optionsDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("objectFitOptions")[0];
  for (let cssValue of [null, 'fill', 'contain', 'cover', 'none', 'scale-down']) {
    let label = document.createElement('label');
    let radio = document.createElement('input');{
    radio.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
    radio.setAttribute('name', 'object-fit');
    radio.setAttribute('value', cssValue);
    radio.onclick=onChange;
    }
    let span = document.createElement('span');
    {
      span.innerText = cssValue || 'Unset';
    }
    label.appendChild(radio);
    label.appendChild(span);
    optionsDiv.appendChild(label);
  }
}

// Onload preform renders
renderRadioButtons();
```

```css
.image-row {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
}

.image-row > * {
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  min-height: 0px;
  min-width: 0px;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: default;
}
```

```html
<div class="objectFitOptions">
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    Small images
  </div>
  <div class="image-row">
    <div>
      <img src="https://object.cato.org/sites/cato.org/files/ra-icons/icon-regulatory.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://clearlawinstitute.com/wpcli/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/icon-investigation.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    Tall images
  </div>
  <div class="image-row">
    <div>
      <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/tall-beech-tree-spring-moving-foliage-42826766.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://clipground.com/images/tall-clipart-4.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    Wide images
  </div>
  <div class="image-row">
    <div>
      <img src="https://photography-cameras.org/images/stories/wide-angle-lens.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://hdqwalls.com/wallpapers/new-york-city-wide-8k-2z.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```